# Fade a UIImageView out and then automatically bring it back in

Tags: fade

Hi guys I am trying to bring back an image automatically after it has faded to alpha 0, but cannot figure it out.

```
[UIImageView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];

[UIImageView setAnimationDuration:4.0];

[_imageflushdownwater setAlpha:0];
self.imageflushdownwater.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(_imageflushdownwater.transform, M_PI / 1);
[UIImageView commitAnimations];
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to figure out, it would have been enough to read through [UIView's class reference...](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW111) (Please! Pretty please!)

Anyways...

Using the old, class-based API (that's what you **are** using):

```
[UIView setAnimationTarget:self];
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(animationFinished:completed:context:)];


- (void)animationFinished:(NSString *)name completed:(NSNumber *)completed context:(void *)ctx
{
    imageView.alpha = 1.0f;
    imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
}
```

Using the new, block-based API (that's what you **should be** using):

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:4.0 animations:^{
    imageView.alpha = 0.0;
    imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI);
} completion:^{
    imageView.alpha = 1.0f;
    imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
}];
```

Comment: this is for a UIView, i have a UIImageView in a UIView, how can i only fade the UIImageView?

Comment: o ###, i readed really bad, sorry